# undefined local variable or method `path'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, blogs

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h2><%= link_to post.title, @post %></h2>
    <p><%= post.content %></p>
    <hr />

<% end %>
```

When i do this it will let me view the page with no errors and have a hyper link on all my post titles but now its not redirecting me to the page with just the post i wanted... Still trying to figure this error on my part i guess, out.

Comment: You are using the variable `path` which is apparently not defined...

Comment: Did you mean `post.path`?

Comment: I define a var. call @post = Post.find(params[:id]) so i put the var in for path and it is working i think now

Comment: @RoySchoep, you dont have to define the path as a variable, provided the `post` is defined as a resource in rails. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have modified post path somehow:

```
<%= link_to 'post.title', post_path(post) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <p><%= post.content %></p>
    <hr />

<% end %>
```

Note that I changed `@post -> post`, because inside the loop you need to get the path for each `post` object.

So then you don't need to do `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`, as you said.